# Ensuring even CPU time distribution among threads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I have a planning algorithm written in Haskell which is tasked with evaluating a set of possible plans in a given amount of time, where the evaluation process is one which may be run for arbitrary amounts of time to produce increasingly accurate results.  The natural and purportedly most efficient way to do this is to give each evaluation task its own lightweight Haskell thread, and have the main thread harvest the results after sleeping for the specified amount of time.

But in practice, invariably one or two threads will be CPU-starved for the entire available time.  My own experimentation with semaphores/etc to control execution has shown this to be surprisingly difficult to fix, as I can't seem to force a given thread to stop executing (including using "yield" from Control.Concurrent.)

Is there a good known way to ensure that an arbitrary number of Haskell threads (not OS threads) each receive a roughly even amount of CPU-time over a (fairly short) span of wall-clock-time?  Failing that, a good way to ensure that a number of threads executing an identical iteration fairly "take turns" on a given number of cores such that all cores are being used?

Comment: Could you have your threads check in with a central scheduling thread every so often... say, every 1000 iterations or something like that?

Comment: Try taking a look at the cooperative thread implementation [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/06/from-zero-to-cooperative-threads-in-33.html). Note you can also evaluate many of these `Thread`s concurrently.

Comment: Make sure that the values shared between threads are evaluated (to [NF](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/latest/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html#t:NFData), for example). How do you exactly measure how much CPU time each thread gets?

Comment: @Wagner - Yes, but then how to have the central thread lock down the evaluation threads that have gone too far ahead, while preventing cases where only one core is left evaluating a thread that's running behind?

Comment: @Petr - Currently I've just been looking at how many iterations each thread gets through, since in all cases a single iteration should take a reasonably similar amount of time.  If there's a function that returns total thread CPU time that would be helpful, though.

Comment: @cdk - From my quick read of it, that appears to deal with a hand-coded reimplementation of threads.  Am I missing some technique there that could be applied to Haskell's native threads?

Comment: It seems like there should be a more appropriate way of doing what you're trying to do, but you might get some ideas from the source of [speculation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/speculation) (or maybe that would even help your problem?)

Comment: @user2433805: Using that implementation, you can schedule your workers to perform a single iteration of their algorithm, then yield control to another worker an so on. You could have groups of workers scheduled on these user-defined threads, ensuring equally (or at least fair) computation time for each and each user-defined thread can be evaluated concurrently on a native OS thread.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Haskell threads should *all* receive roughly equal amounts of CPU power as long as they are all actively trying to do work. The only reason that wouldn't happen is if they start making blocking I/O calls, or if each thread runs only for a few milliseconds or something.

Perhaps the problem you are seeing is actually that each thread just runs for a split second, yielding an unevaluated expression as its result, which the main thread then evaluates itself? If that were the case, it would look like the main thread is getting all the CPU time.